# Curl, Magento, and Paypal. (Curl does not return any errors)

Tags: magento, curl, paypal, checkout

I hope you wont vote my post down cause I dont have code to show for but its a very general question. When I do a curl call to paypal, rather I get a response back or not, curl_getinfo() returns 0. I am getting a intermitten resposne. sometimes I get a response, sometimes I get false, but in either case, I get no error number or getinfo.

So I guess my question is... Is this issue a common issue, is there a setting I can use to get "getinfo()" to actually return something

Answer (score 1):

You should also try checking the error messages in curl_error(). You might need to do this once after each curl_* function.

http://www.php.net/curl_error

Curl comes with an outdated file to authenticate HTTPS certificates from.

get the new one from:

http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

save it into some dir on your site

and add

curl_setopt ($curl_ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(**FILE**)."/cacert.pem");